# If cookie is set for two years then how large number of new users are showing in GA on daily basis?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to know how new and returning users are identifying in Google Analytics. I have explored GA blogs many times but still confused. If cookie is set for two years then how large number of new users are showing in Google Analytics on the daily basis?

Can I edit cookie settings for my website in GA?

I have explored GA blogs many times but still confused. If cookie is set for two years then how large number of new users are showing in Google Analytics on the daily basis?

Can I edit cookie settings for my website in GA?

I am unable to edit cookie setting for my website.

I want to know how can I edit the cookie setting and how Google is determining new and returning users?

Comment: The cookie created by the google analytics library is created by them its not something you should try to change.  I am not really sure why you would want to

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I just want to know how new and returning users are identifying in Google Analytics? If cookie is set for two years then how large number of new users are showing in Google Analytics on the daily basis?

Comment: No one can tell you how many new users are detected by google analytics in a daily basis.   Your basically asking how often every user in the world hits a website with google analytics installed for the first time each day.   I dont even thing google wants to try and calculate that number.